# How to print a character vector 'pretty' in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pretty-print, rnotebook, kable

Is there a function such as kable to output character vectors in a way that doesn't look as ugly as the default console type?

Comment: Show us current output and what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

See eg `p` from the `pander` package or the generic `pander` method:

```
> pander::pander(sample(letters, 5))
_p_, _r_, _v_, _f_ and _t_
```

If you want to override the default formatting, see `panderOptions` or specify directly in the `p` function.